# How to add folders in sharepoint using office365-rest-python-api

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, office365api

I have registered an application in sharepoint with read and write access to the site.
I want to create folders with subfolders and I found solution in official documentation:

```
def create_folder(dir_path):
    ctx = auth()
    target_folder_url = dir_path
    target_folder = ctx.web.ensure_folder_path(target_folder_url).execute_query()
    print(target_folder.serverRelativeUrl)
```

But after call:

```
create_folder("/Shared Documents/Archive/2022/09/01")
```

I got:

```
('-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'Access denied.', "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test_site/_api/Web/RootFolder/Folders/Add('Shared%20Documents'))
```

and when I paste in browser:

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test_site/_api/Web/RootFolder/Folders/Add('Shared%20Documents')
```

I got error like that:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'Add'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

## EDIT:

I figure it out. On permission:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read"/>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Write"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

it's not enough to create folder in that way. I have to change to Full Control:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
          <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
    </AppPermissionRequests>
```